# Receiving ID3 metadata with HLS streams

Tags: google-cast, id3

How do I get ID3 metadata using a web cast receiver?  I have registered event listeners for TIMED_METADATA_CHANGED and ID3 events but they aren't fired when ID3 tags are inserted into the HLS stream.

Using the shaka player directly in a web app, I can do something like the following:

`this.player.addEventListener("metadata", (ev) => { if ((ev.metadataType == 'ID3') || (ev.metadataType == "org.id3")) { ... } });`

I have tried the event handlers in the documentation and tried different versions of the shaka player in CastReceiverOptions to match what I use in a standard web app.  For some reason, the problem seems HLS-specific with chromecast as I get ID3 events for VoD streams or when using HLS with shaka.Player in a web app.

The only documentation specific to this is for an older version of the cast API.